# HP dv6-2155dx Weird Display Issue

Tags: display, graphics, visual-artifacts

I consider myself to be a fairly savvy computer guy, but this is a new one for me - I have an HP dv6-2155dx laptop. It has an integrated Intel HD graphics chipset. There are some scenarios (I haven't been able to nail down the exact steps to reproduce the issue) where the screen seems to fracture in horizontal bands, almost like there are artifacts on the screen, but this is on the desktop with no apps running. I don't really know what steps to take to begin troubleshooting this, let along fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like a flakey cable from the motherboard to lcd. Sometimes moving the angle of the display will flex and hit the bad spot. Any chance the physical position of the screen is related?

Comment: Interesting point; I'll have to check that.